# How can I use nginx as a file paste bin?

Tags: nginx, file-upload, lua

I have a personal nginx web server; how can I use it as uploader for ShareX and similar applications? That is, I want to be able to POST it a file and get an URL to download that file, possibly with a randomized name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this in “pure” nginx. This doesn't use any [PHP](https://github.com/Rouji/single_php_filehost) or other scripts, instead, files are uploaded using [nginx-upload-module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) and the rest is done by Lua.

To get Lua, I used [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/installation.html). I simply compiled that as if it was nginx, adding `--add-module=/path/to/nginx-upload-module`.

Then I created file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/lua_init` with a few general-purpose methods:

```
init_by_lua_block {
    SOURCE_FOLDER = "/tmp/"
    DEST_FOLDER = "/tmp/up/"
    URI_PREFIX = "https://my.website/z/"
    CHARACTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

    function fail(message)
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, message)
        ngx.exit(500) 
    end

    function file_exists(path)
        local file = io.open(path, 'r')
        if file ~= nil then io.close(file) return true else return false end
    end

    function file_move(src, dest)
        local ok, err = os.rename(src, dest)
        if not ok then fail("error while moving file: " .. err) end
    end

    function random_string(max)
        local output = ""
        for i = 1, max do
            local rand = math.random(#CHARACTERS)
            output = output .. string.sub(CHARACTERS, rand, rand)
        end
        return output
    end

    function get_extension(name) -- nilable
        if (string.find(name, "%.tar%.gz$")) then
            return ".tar.gz"
        else
            local _, _, ext = string.find(name, "(%.[^./]+)$");
            return ext
        end
    end

    math.randomseed(os.time())
}
```

Then I created file `upload` in the same directory:

```
location /up {
    upload_pass @up;

    upload_store /tmp;
    upload_store_access user:r;

    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

    # it is safe to put "200-499" here so that other files are also cleaned up
    # this will generate errors in the log though as moved files cannot be deleted
    upload_cleanup 400-599;

    client_max_body_size 512m;
}

location @up {
    content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.req.read_body()

        local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
        
        local _, _, name = string.find(body, "\"file%.name\"\r\n\r\n([^\r\n]+)");
        local _, _, path = string.find(body, "\"file%.path\"\r\n\r\n(" .. SOURCE_FOLDER .. "%d+)");

        if not name or not path then fail("no name or path in request") end

        local ext = get_extension(name)
        
        local new_name, new_path
        for i = 1, 5 do
            new_name = random_string(10)
            if ext then new_name = new_name .. ext end
            new_path = DEST_FOLDER .. new_name
            if not file_exists(new_path) then break end
            if i == 5 then fail("can't find a new file name"); end
        end

        file_move(path, new_path)

        ngx.say(URI_PREFIX .. new_name)
    }
}

location /z {
   alias /tmp/up/;
}
```

Include these files in your main configuration file like this:

```
...
include sites-available/lua_init;

server {
    ...
    include sites-available/upload;
}
```

This works like this. `nginx-upload-module` will save files in location specified by the `upload_store` directive, which is `/tmp/` in my case. Location `@up` will then receive body with file names and paths instead of file contents. The body is parsed using regex to get the values for form field `file`. A new file name is created using a set of random characters and the original extension (.tar.gz is special-cased). A file is then moved to the new name, and an URL is printed as plain text. Make sure source and destination paths are on the same file system!

You can test that this works by running:

```sh
$ curl --form file=@file.txt https://my.website/up
https://my.website/z/j9v0fr6ukh.txt
```

Comment: Instead of `file_move` you can just to `assert(os.rename("src", "dst"))`.